# Python library installation libact: Failed building wheel for libact

Tags: python, pip, package

I am trying to install python library libact but get the following error:

```
Failed building wheel for libact
  Running setup.py clean for libact
Failed to build libact
Installing collected packages: libact
  Running setup.py install for libact ... error
    Complete output from command C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-nmmfnje9\\libact\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-13e1bgj8\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile

No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    building 'libact.query_strategies._variance_reduction' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
```

I tried to install pip install wheel but still shows the same error.

Comment: Could you post the full error message? This is only the summary that an error occured and not much information can be gathered from it

Comment: Updated the error

Comment: Have you tried installing the Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+No+module+named+%27numpy.distutils._msvccompiler%27+in+numpy.distutils

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+error%3A+Microsoft+Visual+C%2B%2B+14.0+is+required

Answer (score 0):

as written [here](https://github.com/FPGAwars/apio/issues/144)

Try to update your packegs:

```
pip install -U setuptools
pip install -U wheel
```

Comment: Thanks, but still is showing the same error.

Comment: @M.TAF can you post more details about the error you get?